# ActionBarSherlock Side Menu Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, drawer

Im trying to use drawer toggle in an action bar with sherlock. This is my main activity:

```
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshAttacher;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.mejorandroid.ejemplo3_clase3.fragments.MainFragment;
import com.mejorandroid.ejemplo3_clase3.fragments.TermsFragment;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
                          implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView drawer_list;
    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawer_toggle;

    private PullToRefreshAttacher pullToRefreshAttacher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);

        drawer_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ArrayAdapter<String> drawer_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(
                        R.array.array_drawer_options));

        drawer_list.setAdapter(drawer_adapter);
        drawer_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        selectItem(0);

        drawer_toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(drawer_toggle);

        getSherlock().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSherlock().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawer_toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawer_toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home || drawer_toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public PullToRefreshAttacher getAttacher() {

        return pullToRefreshAttacher;
    }

    public void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment f;

        if(position==0){
            f = new MainFragment();
        }else{
            f = new TermsFragment();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.main_content, f)
          .commit();

        drawer_list.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(drawer_list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(drawer_list);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}
```

In the method onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home || drawer_toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I get:

[image]

**How can I fix this??**

This is my main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Are you importing the correct `MenuItem` class? ActionBarSherlock provides `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`, whereas the Android SDK's `ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected()` method expects `android.view.MenuItem`.

Comment: Yes, I have added the imports to the question.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/941) and [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/pull/946) for an explanation of why it isn't working, and a number of potential solutions.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/941. I have encountered same issue, as people here explained it expects android MenuItem. However, someone in that link provided a solution: 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
Hope that helps.

Comment: yes this works, thanks. Just last question, how can I display the ic_drawer instead of the up button?

Comment: ActionBar ab = this.getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); I used these for that purpose, cant remember exactly but displayuselogo should do that

Comment: No, that's not working. In newer devices I can see the ic_drawer but in older devices just see the up button..

Comment: Also you have an order issue in your onOptionsItemSelected method! Java will stop to the first "true" in (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home || drawer_toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) so your menu will never be shown :/ because drawer_toggle.onOptionsItemSelected is never called.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same problem and this works for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(drawer_list)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(drawer_list);
        } else {
            drawer_layout.openDrawer(drawer_list);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I don't know if this problem is already fixed in the newest release of the Sherlock library / support library, but the workaround does a good job.

Comment: Yes, this works!! thanks. Just last question, how can I display the ic_drawer instead of the up button?

Comment: Try replacing getSherlock().getActionBar().. with getSupportActionBar(). This is the only difference I can see. If this doesn't work pay some attention to Can Gokderes comment.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. In newer devices I can see the ic_drawer but in older devices just see the up button.. I guess thats another problem. Thanks anyway ;)